Help me identify this chip (8 pins)
The chip has 8 pins with 6 GND pins, 1 input, 1 output. It sits between a RF amplifier in the input and a voltage amplifier in the output with AC coupling caps.


Mini-Circuits LFCG-900+
LTCC Low Pass Filter, DC - 850 MHz, 50Ω



Gotta love LCSC.com's extensive library of actual part photographs, but you should probably credit them in your answer. (assming you are using them)

Thank you very much.
